# How to put quotation marks around only the ends of a string and then separate outputs by comma in R?

Tags: r, string

I have a couple hundred institution names that I would like to reformat. Currently they are in a vector, with just the college name in the each observation.

Is there a way to output this so that each college has text quotes around each name (so that it appears like "State University"), and then separate each observation by a comma? I tried using the paste() command, but the quotation marks seemed to make it so that I couldn't quote the punctuation attended.

Desired plain text output using write() function would be something like:

```
"State University", "Private University", "State Rival"
```

Replicable example:

```
 state <- c("State University", "Private University", "Rival State")
```

Comment: Do you need `toString(dQuote(state, FALSE))`

Comment: @Auresm, I don't understand. Could you please explain. Do you want to write it in a file?

Comment: @TarJae the goal is to have it in a plain text format, which was achieved through writing it as a .txt file

Comment: Ok. I see. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can nest `paste()` to get what you want:

```
paste(paste("\"", state, "\"", sep = ""), collapse = ",")
```

The inner `paste()` quotes each element in your character vector, then the outer `paste()` joins / collapses the vector into one string.

If you have the package `stringr` installed, you can do it in one call:

```
library(stringr)
str_c("\"", state, "\"", collapse = ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sprintf` and `toString` to construct the string and `writeLines` to write the output to text file.

```
writeLines(toString(sprintf('"%s"', state)), "temp.txt")
```

[image]